# Find list of images(may be .jpg) using python without knowing the path.

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it possible to search images in system using python code? Ex if I don't know a file location/path and I would like to list it through python. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  You could start at the root, and `os.walk` your way down every directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a dirty solution that I came up with.

```
import os

# "." is your current directory. Feel free to pass any root path.
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(".", topdown=False): 
    for name in files:
        if(name.endswith("jpg")):
           print name
```

Comment: import glob,os
for root,dirs,files in os.walk("C:\\New folder","*.png"):
    #print(files)
    for i in glob.glob(root.join("*.png")):
        #print(root)
        root.remove(files)

O/p:
['abc(2).PNG', 'abc.PNG', 'Test doc 1.txt']
['abc(2).PNG', 'abc.PNG', 'Test doc 1.txt']
>>> root
'C:\\New folder\\New folder'
>>> dirs
[]
>>> files
['abc (2).PNG', 'abc.PNG', 'Test doc 1.txt']
>>>

Comment: When I tried this, it is listing all files present in the folder/directory. I need to fetch only *png images and delete them. Could you please help me on this?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I got what I was looking for :)